# Update color canvas issue

Tags: android, canvas, maze

```
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    Paint paint=new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    Paint paint1=new Paint(Color.WHITE);

     for(int i=0;i<31;i++){
         for(int j=0;j<28;j++){
             float x = j * 10;
             float y = i * 10;
             if(mapa[i][j]==0) {

                 canvas.drawRect(0, 0, y, x, paint);
                 invalidate();

             }else if (mapa[i][j]==1) {

                 canvas.drawRect(0, 0, y, x, paint1);
             }
             refreshDrawableState();
         }
    }

}
```

I want to create a maze, with a matrix. This matrix has values 0-1 (0-Black and 1-White) and I want to draw a maze. In my activity I create this view and use the function setContentView and I can create a black squares. I need some help, maybe exist a function to update the canvas or stuff like that

Comment: please initialize any thing outside onDraw() and invalidate method to update your canvas. and according to my understand you want to update your view from a different method ??

Comment: I want to create a Pacman maze, but I get a huge square of 1 color (In this case, a huge black square). It can't draw white square

Comment: there is an logical issue you have to pass drawRect Left, and Right value according to square size instead of 0,0 add squre width in left parameter .
drawRect(Left,Top,Right,Bottom)

Comment: At the moment I follow your suggestion, but I can only draw 1 rectangle (10x10)in the canvas, and I don't know why